# Execute command prompt query from C# Windows Desktop App

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I am running this code in previous versions of Visual Studio 2013 Pro - C# Forms App, and it is working perfectly fine. 
However I have now downloaded the Visual Studio 2017 Community and the same code is not working anymore. It is just opening the command prompt blank window and doesn't execute any commands.

[image]

Also, it is not even asking for any admin privileges now.

Can anyone please suggest, how should I get this working in community edition.
Thanks.

```
        Process p1 = new Process();
        p1.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        p1.StartInfo.Arguments = "java";
        p1.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p1.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        p1.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
        p1.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
        p1.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
        p1.Start();
        p1.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: not working anymore: does not compile, throws an exception at runtime, ... ? please add more information about the problem.

Comment: sorry for the vague term. updated

Comment: you are starting cmd.exe with "java" as its argument. when I do the same in Windows 10, run, "cmd.exe java", a new command window opens and nothing else is happening. what do you expect? that the java command-line help is shown?

Comment: `p1.StartInfo.Verb = "runas ";` should be  `p1.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";`

Comment: I wrote just the sample code. even if i try something else now, it's not being executed like in place of cmd.exe i tried writing netsh.exe and arguments as "wlan start hosted network"

Comment: @jAC: Same thing happens when I remove that last space as well

Comment: do you `p1.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()` after the process is started? I think you need to do that since you set `RedirectStandardOutput` to true

Comment: @dlatikay Added ur code p1.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd() as well, but its not giving any fruitful results

Comment: Btw.: `UseShellExecute` has to be `true` (this requires `RedirectStandardOutput` to be `false`) if you want an UAC prompt.

Comment: @jAC: It is showing this error, and command prompt opens with blank window when I do so - http://i.imgur.com/lzxtch9.png

Comment: Of course, since you cannot have a UAC prompt and redirect the streams. What are you trying to achieve? Are you trying to open an elevated program and getting the output/sending input to it from your running program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are missing /c from your arguments

p1.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c java";

```
  Process p1 = new Process();
        p1.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd";
        p1.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c java";
        p1.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p1.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        p1.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        p1.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";

        p1.Start();

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while (!(p1.StandardOutput.EndOfStream))
             sb.Append($"{ p1.StandardOutput.ReadLine()}");


        while (!(p1.StandardError.EndOfStream))
            sb.Append($"{ p1.StandardError.ReadLine()}");

        p1.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: p1.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd(); is giving error in my case. it is showing the process hasn't yet started