# Not getting output while running cmd file of remote using PsExec in c#

Tags: c#, cmd, process, psexec

I am not able to read output after running cmd file of remote using PsExe.exe in c#. Below is my attempt:

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
p.StartInfo.FileName = @"D:\path\PsExec.exe";
string pargs = @"\\servername -u <username> -p <password> cmd /c C:\\path\\Test.cmd";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = pargs;
p.Start();
p.WaitForExit();

 string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
 MessageBox.Show("output=" + output);
 MessageBox.Show("error=" + p.StandardError.ReadToEnd());`
```

Here is the [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTsRt.jpg)

Here is the [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aanFF.jpg.) I received

However if I try to execute following command form local it is working fine and I can see output there.

`Psexec //servername -u username -p password cmd /c C:\\path\\Test.cmd`

Note:- `Test.cmd` also has `pause` statement

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45970137/execute-command-prompt-query-from-c-sharp-windows-desktop-app/45970354#45970354

Comment: Stuart,  you mentioned thread is different one. This is with psexec

Comment: Above code is working file if I replace PsExec.exe file with PAExec.exe (https://www.poweradmin.com/paexec/). But not sure whether it is safe to use??